# Close as duplicate in SE meta

Tags: feature-request

Given we now have a shiny new SE Meta site for network wide changes it would be great to get a close as duplicate on the other site.

Here's a really good example of a question that should be closed as a duplicate:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252281/latex-support-in-so

duplicate of MSE:

[LaTeX on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow)

(even though the origional probably doesnt belong on SE meta at all)

Links renaming seems to work cross-site, can close as duplicate get relaxed to work cross site (if only for specific meta to general meta)

Shog9 has now closed this question as a duplicate using his mod tools I assume but I certainly couldn't, I get the following error:

```
The duplicate question must exist on Meta Stack Overflow
```

Comment: I tend to agree something should be done (although I'm not sure whether a simple duplicate-closing is the way to go). There is value in having *some* fundamental discussions on both local Metas and Meta.SE, but the way things currently stand we're slowly replicating thousands of feature requests on Meta.SO that already have been made on the old Meta, that are now on Meta.SE - because they're not discoverable on Meta.SO's search. What sense does that make?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yeah perhaps this isnt far enough, but it was a bit irritating and im sure ChrisF ran into the same issue as i did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two cases here:

1. The question is Stack Overflow specific. In this case the old question should be flagged for an SE employee to migrate here (as it's strictly off topic on Meta SE) and then the new question *can* be closed as a duplicate.

   In the case you mention an employee spotted the question, migrated the original here and then closed the question as a duplicate.
2. The question is a network issue. While it's correct that it's posted here it does make things a little more awkward. The new question *could* be migrated to to Meta SE where it would be closed as a duplicate.

   However, this seems to be just making work for the Stack Overflow moderators and Stack Exchange employees. In this case it's probably best to either add a comment or, if a little more explanation is required, an answer linking to the Meta Stack Exchange question.

Comment: Actually thats not quite what happened (but it probably should) Shog9 found another duplicate which is on SO meta and closed it as a duplicate of that one. Really all three questions belong on SO meta i think

Comment: or moved a different one?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - Shog found the original original, not just another duplicate that I found.

Comment: lol fun and games with duplicates